# How to drop everything after a date using a groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like that:

| Date | Type | Client |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-04-25 | 1 | C |
| 2020-04-26 | 1 | A |
| 2020-04-26 | 2 | C |
| 2020-04-27 | 2 | A |
| 2020-05-01 | 2 | B |
| 2020-05-01 | 3 | D |
| 2020-05-02 | 3 | A |
| 2020-05-01 | 4 | A |
| 2020-05-02 | 4 | B |
| 2020-05-03 | 4 | D |

And I would like to keep only the ones before the apparition of Client A (group by **Type** and order by **Date**):

**Final result**

| Date | Type | Client |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-04-25 | 1 | C |
| 2020-04-26 | 1 | A |
| 2020-04-26 | 2 | C |
| 2020-04-27 | 2 | A |
| 2020-05-01 | 3 | D |
| 2020-05-02 | 3 | A |
| 2020-05-01 | 4 | A |

To explain, for example:
I droped B from type 2 because 2020-05-01 came after 2020-04-27 (Client A, same type)

I found a solution but it's very long and I am sure I could find something better only using pandas. Thank you for your help!!

Comment: It's not crystal clear what you want, but if you want all records before the last 'A' this would do - `df.loc[df.index<=df.loc[df['Client']=='A'].index.max()]`

Comment: Do you want to group by Type as well or not - on the 26th of April you have two rows in your output with type 1 and with type 2, for the 2020-05-01 you have only one row picked up with 3

Comment: I reformulate my question.

Comment: @AnnaSemjén Yes, it's group by Type. I want to keep only what is before A of the same Type